"Job ntopng.service/stop running" keeps my system from shutting down for 1 minute and 30 seconds
I dual boot Ubuntu 24.10 and Windows 11 and I need to restart a lot to switch OSs. I have been always aware how slow Ubuntu shut down, but I never thought too much about it. A few days ago I pressed Esc to see what processes were going on and I saw this process as it appears in this screenshot to be taking 1 minute and 30 seconds each time.

To me it feels like it's just a countdown with no real process behind it because as soon as the 90 seconds pass, the computer shuts down immediately. Is there any way to skip this timeout and shutdown without waiting?
